# Mesh deform modifier not working

Tags: mesh

Im new to blender, and i made a simple mesh with simple rigging but as i try to move it around the mesh gets all squished up and stuff, so internet said its good to use "mesh deform modifier", so i tried, but it says "modifier disabled, skipped to apply"

Then i thought maybe my mesh is all messed up, so i tried it on a simple cube, but still the same problem.

I looked for solutions but nothing really helps, some said to use "boolean modifier" but same problem, it is disabled..

Pls help

[image]

Comment: The answer I gave is concerning the mesh deform modifier as it is the question. But it seems that you had a previous problem with rigging : if needed you may ask another question about that. Rigging is a much more conventional way to animate an object and mesh deform is much more limited at doing a rig.

Answer (score 5):

Mesh deform (and other modifiers, like boolean) uses two objects.

For mesh deform :

- The first one is the one to be deformed : the modifier is defined on this object
- The second one is the deforming object : it has to be set in the '*object*' field of the modifier

An example :

Here two objects : the cylinder will be the object to be deformed and the cube is the deforming object. The cube must surround the parts of the cylinder we want to be deformed. So it is easier to hide the cube faces to see the cylinder inside :

[image]

Now select the cylinder, add the modifier and set the cube as deforming object :

[image]

This modifier has a particularity : Blender needs to do some calculations before the modifier can be used. As these calculations can be a bit long, it is needed to click on the "bind" button to make it work (above the calculation time, bind/unbind is also a way to change the initial configuration if needed, clicking on the 'unbind' button available once the binding is done).

Once bound, you can edit the cube mesh to deform the cylinder :

[image]

But you can also use other modifiers on the cube to deform it and the cylinder will follow. Here an example with an armature modifier set to the cube. So the armature influences the cube and the mesh deform modifier influences the cylinder as the cube is transformed :

[image]

Concerning the warning you indicate in your question : this is because the object field is not defined in the modifier panel.

The "apply" button (for all modifiers) is used to freeze/transform the object at the position (or geometry, etc.) it is when you apply. And once applied the concerned object is really modified and the modifier disappears from the panel.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question, but my problem is my mesh is not a closed shape. I make holes to extrude here and there, but forgot to close the face.

When you press Bind, no error will comes up but it will be very fast and it will not work at all.

Comment: I have the same problem, but my mesh is not open at all. I cannot get any object to deform with mesh deform at all. No error is thrown. The unbind button does not appear, which makes me think that the binding process gets interrupted somehow.